# Is there a way to disable InputLabel in Input Components like SelectInput and TextInput?

Tags: react-admin

I am looking for a solution to disable the labels in the input components so that they never render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label attribute of the TextInput component can take either a string or a boolean value: `label={false}`.

In the component this is SelectInput, this also works, but there will be an error in the console, therefore, you can do this: `label=""`

Comment: Thank you. I had to adjust the CSS as well for the SelectInput but it worked.